# how to fix this error 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append' in the code below

Tags: python, numpy, append

Returns this error:
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

```
class1 = np.array([]) #creates 2 empty arrays
class2 = np.array([])

#yhat_tr is a vector(1 column, 100 rows) = numpy.ndarray
for i in yhat_tr: 
  if i < 0:
    class1.append([i]) #insert the iten in the array class1 or class2
  else:
    class2.append([i])
```

I want to insert new array itens inside the class1 or class2 arrays as soon the itens are evaluated inside the loop.
After that i will try to print the results in a scatter graphic with 2 colors where i can identify visually the class1 and class2 elements.

Comment: Use just lists. Why do you need `np.array` ? e.g. `class1= []`

Comment: append is a python list function. Are you sure it should exist on numpy.ndarray? pydoc numpy.ndarray may prove helpful.

Comment: The `append` method works on Python lists and not numpy arrays.

Comment: @RafaelC, i have to make some mathematical operations with the itens like multiplicate anoter array with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Alex mentioned, numpy arrays dont have append method. You can use his suggestion to use numpy append method or You might want to define class variables as lists and use append and convert them to array after the loop as the code below does.

```py
class1 = []
class2 = []

#yhat_tr is a vector(1 column, 100 rows) = numpy.ndarray
for i in yhat_tr: 
  if i < 0:
    class1.append([i]) #insert the iten in the array class1 or class2
  else:
    class2.append([i])

class1 = np.array(class1)
class2 = np.array(class2)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add a NumPy array element by using the append() method of the NumPy module.

The syntax of append is as follows:

```
numpy.append(array, value, axis)
```

The values will be appended at the end of the array and a new ndarray will be returned with new and old values as shown above.

The axis is an optional integer along which define how the array is going to be displayed. If the axis is not specified, the array structure will be flattened

Comment: Don't use `np.append`.  It is just a poorly named cover for `np.concatenate`, and is often misused.  Using lists and list append is better.

Answer (score 4):

A quick look at the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) shows that `np.ndarray` objects do not have a function `append`, it is a function of `np` itself:

```
class1 = np.append(class1, [i])
```

Answer (score -1):

Love how the famous Stackoverflow is so full of judgemental posters. Making this not much better than Facebook.

You need to up your game SO.

[image]